# How to pass variables between two templates in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How to pass variables between two templates in XSLT.

I cannot use global variable because value of variable is dependent on current node under evaluation.

Say I have XSLT of sort:

```
<xsl:template match="product">
<xsl:variable name="pr-pos" select="count(./preceding-sibling::product)+1"/>
..
..
..
<xsl:apply-templates select="countries/country"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="countries/country">
<tr id="country-id">
  <td><a href="#" class="action" id="{concat('a-',$pr-pos)}">+</a></td>
..
..
```

This gives error as $pr-pos  is not accessible in second template.

How do I pass variable pr-pos' value to other template? How can I do this?

Comment: In your case you don't really need to pass a variable. The value of `$pr-pos` that you wish to pass is discernable from within the `country` template.

Comment: All programming languages (well, most) have a means to pass information to another execution unit, and learning how to do that is one of the fundamentals. This question is roughly equivalent to asking, how to I pass variables between two functions in JavaScript, or saying "I tried `function a(){ var i=5; b(); } function b(){ alert(i); }` but `i` is not accessible in second function."

Comment: @torazaburo: I could not one useful which explains me how to do this on google.I din't knew it that's why asked, if you have problem from people asking questions why don't you disable your account on StackOverflow. Search google and tell me you find any good document on this other than w3 documentation.

Comment: @Utkanos: No it isn't. You are supposed to explicitly pass 'local variable'to other templates as shown in answer below.

Comment: @Harshdeep - sorry, but it really is - [allow me to prove it](http://www.xmlplayground.com/o50iqf). You *can* pass variables, but that does mean you have to. In fact, you will find that the explicit passing of variables between templates (except in the case of named templates) is actually quite uncommon.

Comment: @Utkanos: you are a XML Guru :) Sorry I din't get what you were trying to say the first time. I thought you are saying the above snippet won't raise any error and I can use pr-pos just like that in 2nd template. Thanks for the help again. Caught in a XSLT project and you are always there to help. :)

Comment: No problem - was only clarifying. XSLT can be tough to get your head round to start with. You'll pick it up in no time :)

Comment: @Harshdepp, to take just one example, not necessarily recommended, consider the XSLT tutorial at http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Output/contents.html and check out page 34, "Parameters for a template can be passed with xsl:with-param element." I would suggest that instead of trying to learn basic aspects of a programming language by Googling, that you sit down and go through some kind of course or tutorial such as this. If you really want to learn basics by Googling, a search for "pass arguments to an xslt template" immediately brought up relevant pages for me. What did you try searching for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:variable name="pr-pos" select="count(./preceding-sibling::product)+1"/>
    ..
    ..
    ..
    <xsl:apply-templates select="countries/country">
       <xsl:with-param name="pr-pos" select="$pr-pos" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="countries/country">
  <xsl:param name="pr-pos" />
    <tr id="country-id">
      <td><a href="#" class="action" id="{concat('a-',$pr-pos)}">+</a></td>
      ..
      ..
```

Comment: I searched some more and did exactly the same thing, before checking for the answer on StackOverflow, and it WORKED. Then too thanks for your help :)